# Is it possible to comment/uncomment a line in vim with "ctrl+/"

Tags: vim

Newbie here. I am looking for an easier way in `VIM` to comment/uncomment (just one line commenting, which is the most frequent commenting type) for `C++` codes using just **one** shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (without going to the visual mode). Is it possible to achieve this effect by mapping without using 3rd party plug-in such as nerd? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieve it with the following mappings (<kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to comment, <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> to uncomment)

```
map <leader>/ :s/^\(\s*\)/\1\/\/ <CR>:noh<CR>
map <leader>? :s/^\(\s*\)\/\/\(\s*\)/\1<CR>:noh<CR>
```

- `^\(\s*\)` Matches from the start of a line up to the first non-whitespace character.
- `\1\/\/` replaces the captured whitespace (`\1`) with the same whitespace followed by `//`

The remaining stuff `<CR>:noh<CR>` turns off the search pattern highlighting, so as not to leave all leading whitespace highlighted in the buffer.

I only use them as normal mode mappings, not insert mode. In normal mode (with mapleader as `,` I can do things like <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to comment the next 4 lines, but it isn't smart enough to comment everything in an inner `{}` for example.

It is not nearly as tidy as something like NERDCommenter produces. For example, it would turn this:

```
if (thing) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Into this:

```
// if (thing) {
  // doSomething();
// }
```

When something like this would be preferable.

```
// if (thing) {
//   doSomething();
// }
```

I apply the mappings via `autocmd` in the `//`-comment languages I frequently use:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,php,javascript map <leader>/ :s/^\(\s*\)/\1\/\/ <CR>:noh<CR>
autocmd FileType c,cpp,php,javascript map <leader>? :s/^\(\s*\)\/\/\(\s*\)/\1<CR>:noh<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

They don't use `<C-/>` as the key binding, but for pretty complete solutions see [tcomment.vim](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) or [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

I use the following quick'n'dirty solution which makes `//` comment out a line depending on filetype, but it has several flaws (e.g. not being repeatable with `.`):

```
  " make // comment out a line
  au FileType *                            nmap <buffer> // 0i# <Esc>
  au FileType vim                          nmap <buffer> // I" <Esc>
  au FileType sh,zsh,csh,tcsh,make         nmap <buffer> // I# <Esc>
  au FileType html,xhtml,xml,xslt,dtd,xsd  nmap <buffer> // I<!-- <Esc>A --><Esc>
  au FileType sql,haskell                  nmap <buffer> // I-- <Esc>
  au FileType c                            nmap <buffer> // I/* <Esc>A */<Esc>
  au FileType cpp                          nmap <buffer> // I// <Esc>
```