# vim: mapping key to comment with indentation

Tags: vim, comments, mapping, indentation

Before I was using this in .vimrc to use '+' and '-' to comment the code has been highlighted:

```
noremap <silent>+ :s/^/\/\/ /<CR>:noh<CR>
noremap <silent>- :s/^\/\/ //<CR>:noh<CR>
```

so when I comment the code it becomes:

```
int main() {
//     int x = 0;
//     int y = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to comment codes with indents, like the following:

```
int main() {
    // int x = 0;
    // int y = 0;
    return x;
}
```

However I try to use:

```
noremap <silent>+ :le<CR>:s/^/\/\/ /<CR>==:noh<CR>                              
noremap <silent>- :le<CR>:s/^\/\/ //<CR>==:noh<CR>
```

The commenting result looks like:

```
int main() {
    // int x = 0;
int y = 0;
    return x;
}
```

I was wondering what is wrong with my mapping and how I can fix it...

In addition, is there a "smarter" way to do this?

(I am willing to learn to write a mapping instead of installing some plugins such as NERDcommenter)

Thanks,

## Update:

Maybe I didn't put my questions clear so there are some answers below didn't get what I meant...

Many thanks to everyone who attempted to answer my question, I found Ben's solution is easiest to understand for beginners and rc0r's has less lines as well as it works with multiple level of indentation (even though I don't know what it really does, I will do some self-studying later).

So now the code I use looks like:

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,verilog noremap <silent><Leader>. :s:^\(\s*\):\1// :<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,verilog noremap <silent><Leader>, :s:^\(\s*\)// :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType sh,zsh,python,perl,ruby noremap <silent><Leader>. :s:^\(\s*\):\1# :<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType sh,zsh,python,perl,ruby noremap <silent><Leader>, :s:^\(\s*\)# :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType vim noremap <silent><Leader>. :s:^\(\s*\):\1" :<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType vim noremap <silent><Leader>, :s:^\(\s*\)" :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType asm noremap <silent><Leader>. :s:^\(\s*\):\1; :<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType asm noremap <silent><Leader>, :s:^\(\s*\); :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType vhdl,sql noremap <silent><Leader>. :s:^\(\s*\):\1-- :<CR>:noh<CR>
    autocmd FileType vhdl,sql noremap <silent><Leader>, :s:^\(\s*\)-- :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
endif
```

and it works well enough to me.

Comment: Does this work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959791/is-it-possible-to-comment-uncomment-a-line-in-vim-with-ctrl/19959930#19959930 Every line will be indented, but not necessarily all at the same indent level.

Comment: Use a plugin like vim-commentary https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert for setting up vim maps, but with a slightly modified search and replace pattern your initial map should do the trick:

```
noremap <silent>+ :s:^\(\s*\):\1// :<CR>:noh<CR>
noremap <silent>- :s:^\(\s*\)// :\1:<CR>:noh<CR>
```

The above regex used for commenting searches for a variable number of space characters at the beginning of a line (`^\(\s*\)`) and replaces the found pattern with itself (using a back reference `\1`) followed by the characters for the comment (`\1//`). The second regex shown above removes the comment chars in a similar way: search for variable number of spaces followed by comment characters (`^\(\s*\)//`) and replace all that with just the spaces (back reference `\1`).

Comment: For more info on VIM regular expressions check for example http://www.vimregex.com.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using the map on a visual selection.

The problem, then, is that your initial `:left` command in your mapping ends visual mode, so that the next `:s` command only acts on the current line instead of the entire visual selection.

You have a couple options:

1. Use `gv` to return to visual mode on the last visual selection
2. Use `:'<,'>s` instead of plain `:s` to explicitly set the range to the last visual selection

Either way, you should probably change your `noremap` to `xnoremap` instead, so that it only applies in visual mode. You can make another separate `nnoremap` mapping for normal-mode on a single line without the `gv` or `'<,'>`

Answer (score 0):

There's no doubt a better way to do it :) but the following

```
noremap <silent>+ :le<CR>gv:'<,'>s/^\/\/ ../\/\/ /<CR>gv==:noh<CR>
```

changes

```
int main() {
  //   int x = 0;
  //   int y = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

to

```
int main() {
    // int x = 0;
    // int y = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Didn't have time to work out the uncomment one yet nor work out how best not to repeat the bits in the substitue

Answer (score 0):

Your command adds `//` to the begining of the line because you forgot to take whitespace into consideration:

```
:s/^\s*/\/\/ /
```

But you should use a plugin instead.